# In Android how to stop saving a PDF using Print API.?

Tags: android

I am trying to stop saving a PDF file using print API in Android, but it is not working.

```
private void doPrint() {
    // Get a PrintManager instance
    PrintManager printManager = (PrintManager) getActivity()
            .getSystemService(Context.PRINT_SERVICE);

    // Set job name, which will be displayed in the print queue
    String jobName = getActivity().getString(R.string.app_name) + " Document";

    // Start a print job, passing in a PrintDocumentAdapter implementation
    // to handle the generation of a print document
    printManager.print(jobName, new MyPrintDocumentAdapter(getActivity()),
            null); //
}
```

Comment: "It's not working" is not enought. Do you have some errors traceback ?

Comment: There is no error. I didn't find the flag to stop the saving a PDF. @iFlo

Comment: Means, the doPrint method is not called. :)

Comment: @Nabin do Print Method is called, but in developer.android.com there is not mentioned for disable save pdf option.

Comment: Have you solved this? Please share the answer, if you have found.

Comment: @JagjeetSingh Did you find any solution?